# Cordova: building to remote ios device, can you view local storage & indexedDB

Tags: cordova, visual-studio-cordova

When using cordova if I build to the ripple emulator (which opens in Chrome), I can use the Chrome DevTools --> Resource tab to view what I currently have stored in Local Storage and IndexedDB.

When I then build to a remote IOS device (iPAD) connected through a Mac, is there some way I can similarly view what is currently stored in Local Storage and IndexedDB?

Answer (score 0):

You have to choices:

1. Safari: 
   You have to enable developer tools in the preferences and then you you a new menu item. There you find a lot of tools.
2. Weinre: 
   If you don't own a mac or if you want to have a solution for all your devices, you can use Weinre, found here:

https://people.apache.org/~pmuellr/weinre-docs/latest/

Comment: You can use safari on windows too

Comment: Safari on windows is no more supported.

Comment: yeah, but I think you can still use it, will check.

Comment: when I use Cordova on my windows machine to remotely build to my IPad through my Mac, the build all works fine, but when I go to the Developer menu on Safari, I see the webpage listed there but it is greyed out.